# How To Re-use A Vector In Android XML With A Different Color

Tags: android, xml, colors, drawable, android-vectordrawable

Let's say I have a complex vector image. The path data has a fillColor. I am using an API that demands a drawable resource ID. I want to give this API three different vector images, where the only difference is the color.

I cannot find a way to tint the vector image from XML, only programmatically. I thought the following *might* work, but it does not.

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_awesome_bar_play"
        android:tint="#a8a8a8" />
```

I've also thought about using a layer-list, but this doesn't supporting tinting to my knowledge. Anyone know how to not make three copies of this vector image?

Comment: you will have to do that from java code i'm afraid

Comment: make a copy of the vector image and change the `fillColor`?